# Quadratic matrix function belongs to a positive semidefinite cone

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Is there any idea to the following problem?

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle\operatorname*{minimize}_{(X,y)\in\mathbb S^{p}\times \mathbb R}
& -y\\
\operatorname*{subject to}
& F_1 X+X  F_1^T+XRX+y Q \preceq 0\\
& X \in \mathbb S^{p}_+\\
& y>0
\end{array}
$$

I know it is a convex optimization problem since $R$ is positive semidefinite, but I don't know which kind of problem it belongs to. Thank you for any kind ideas.

Comment: $ F_1 X+X  F_1^T+XRX+y Q \preceq 0$ seems like a generalized ellipsoid. I am not sure if it is OK to do the projection onto this guy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it is convex, so it is currently a convex nonlinear semidefinite program. It is easily rewritten as a linear semidefinite program by performing a Schur complement on the quadratic term, i.e. writing $A - BSS^TB\succeq 0$ as $\left[\begin{array}& A & BS\\S^TB^T &I\end{array}\right]\succeq 0$ (in your case $R = SS^T, B=X, A = -yQ-F_1X-F_1^TX$)

Small detail though that strict inequalities aren't supported in practical theory, you would have to write it as $y\geq \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$ in practice. In your case no reason to add any such constraint though. If the largest possible $y$ is non-positive, you know the original problem is infeasible.